# Criar um validation Request no Laravel com a regra unique

Tags: php, laravel

Criei um request com o comando:

> php artisan make:request NomedoRequest

E no controller estou chamando ele assim:

```
public function nomeDaFuncao(NomedoRequest $request)
{

}
```

Só que preciso usar esse request em duas situações, tanto na hora de criar algum dado, quanto na hora de editar, porém um desses campos eu preciso que seja unico no banco.
No Laravel tem o validation unique que me permite falar que aquele dado precisa ser único, só que se eu tento passar  o mesmo dado na hora de editar, ele apresenta erro falando q é igual.

Eu achei essa funcionalidade

> Rule::unique('tabela')->ignore($email)

Mas não sei como passar essa variável $email para o request que criei e mesmo passando, ela só vai funcionar para uma situação, ou editar, ou criar. Função do request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'cpf' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'birthdate' => 'required',
        'sex' => 'required',
        'email' => ['required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($variavel)],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode configurar as regras conforme o método utilizado.

Dentro do FormRequest tem acesso ao *request(), route(), method()*, etc...

```
public function rules()
    {

        $regras = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'cpf' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'birthdate' => 'required',
            'sex' => 'required'
        ];
        // store
        if ($this->method() === "POST") {
            $regras['email'] = [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('users')
            ];
        } 

         // update
        else {
            $regras['email'] = [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->request->get('email'), 'email')
            ];
        }
        return $regras;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bata colocar a rule no seu validator ao realizar o update basta não colocar unique, que o unique só vai no create

```
protected $rules = [
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
        ],
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
            'email' => 'required',
        ],
    ];

    protected $messages = [
        'email.unique' => 'E-mail já cadastrado',
    ];
```

E no seu controller faça

```
    public function __construct(MinhaClasseValidator $validator) {
      $this->validator = $validator;
    }

public function create(Request $request) {
    $this->validator->with($request->all())->passesOrFail(ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você está dentro de uma ClasseRequest, o $this é o próprio request. Então você pode referenciar algo que foi enviado no seu form usando:

```
$this->campo_do_form
```

Então dentro da sua ClasseRequest faça assim:

```
public function rules()
{
    $validations  = [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'cpf' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'birthdate' => 'required',
        'sex' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:nome_da_tabela,email',
    ];

    if($this->method('PUT')) {
        // para uma tabela SEM campos created_at,updated_at e deleted_at
        $validations['email'] .= ',' . $this->pk_da_tabela . ',pk_da_tabela';

        // para uma tabela COM campos created_at,updated_at e deleted_at
        $validations['email'] .= ',' . $this->pk_da_tabela . ',pk_da_tabela,deleted_at,NULL';
    }

    return $validations;
}
```

referência: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique